# Vertically aligning list bullet when using \infer

Tags: spacing, itemize

I have a list where one of the list items is an `\infer{...}{...}` command. In this case, the list bullet is not vertically centered with the item, as you can see in the picture:

[image]

How can I move the list bullet at the height of the bar?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{proof}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item \infer{Something}{Something else}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Unfortunately it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\vcenter` box command, which centers its contents (just above) the baseline.  It is used for big operators etc. and requires you to be in maths mode.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{proof}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item \( \vcenter{\infer{\textit{Something}}{\textit{Something else}}} \)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```